# Expo app cannot see env variable from Github action

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, environment-variables, expo, github-actions

We store our configurations on the vault and during the Github action workflow we pull this and intend to use this for the app during build time.

This is our workflow

```
- name: Get app configs from vault
  env:
    ENVIRONMENT: development
  run: |
    chmod +x scripts/ci/get-app-configs.sh
    scripts/ci/get-app-configs.sh
    echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Set .env to process.env of github actions
  uses: cardinalby/export-env-action@v1
  with:
    envFile: '.env'
    expand: 'true'

- name: Generate APK
  env:
    EXPO_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.EXPO_TOKEN }}
  run: |
    echo "${{ env.action_state }}"
    echo ${{ env.FIREBASE }}
    eas build --platform android --local --profile development --non-interactive
```

The `Get app configs from vault` step creates an `.env` file with the following contents

```
FIREBASE={firebase_config_string}
```

And then inside `firebase.ts` we do this.

```
const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE as string) as FirebaseOptions;
```

The app works fine when testing on an emulator but when testing the actual APK on a physical device, it always crashes. And in the logcat I keep seeing this error `E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined", stack:`.

I've already narrowed it down to the `firebase.ts` `process.env` since the app doesn't crash when the config is hard coded.

I can see the `env.FIREBASE` as an env variable inside the `Generate APK` step so it's being passed to other steps fine. And the `echo` also prints out the value fine.

Is it not possible to access the env variables of Github action within the code during build time? Or are there other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kept the github workflow as it is.

Fixed by using `expo-constants`.

Renaming the `app.json` to `app.config.js` to be able to add the following lines:

```
import 'dotenv/config';

export default {
  expo: {
    extra: {
      ENV_VAR: process.env.ENV_VAR,
    },
  },
};
```

And access the said variable from the app by

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const ENV_VAR = Constants.manifest?.extra?.ENV_VAR
```